Authorize.Net’s iframe exposes the token, anyone to use it to authorize a transaction. How can we securely hide the token within the iframe
Below are code where token has visible and can access it outside the domain.
<form id="send_token" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" method="post" target="AuthNetIFrame">


The hidden input stores the payment token securely within the form, making it available for submission without displaying it in the UI. wrap the field inside the form tag
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="Token" value="">

